# How to disable back button of windows phone after one click

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a problem in my app is that when the user hit back button multiple times the app become crashed.Is there any way to handle this problem ?Is any way to disable back button after the first click from a page.so further click can be avoided.The exception i am getting  while hitting  back button multiple time is 0x8000ffff.Is there any solution for this in windows phone 7.1?

Comment: It would be better to fix the bug, rather than try to disable the button. Have you been able to reproduce under the debugger?

Comment: The bug occurs as follows.if i have 4 pages named A,B,C,D then from the page D i hit back key multiple times repeatedly and the click more than 5 the app will crash.Is this the problem regarding to back stack?

Answer (score 3):

You should fix the issue which is causing your app to crash. If you disable the back button behaviour you risk failing marketplace certification due to requirement 5.2.4[.1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184840(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can control that, here is a sample code:

```
    private void YourPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //App.NaviService.BackKeyPress(sender, e);
        if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
        {
            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
    }
```